# Does WebSQL support primary keys?

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome, ddl, web-sql, dml

I'm creating a WebSQL table in Chrome with the following statement:

```
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recs(id, fname,lname,email,country,comments, synced     integer,PRIMARY KEY(id))'
```

Inserting records does not appear to be creating primary keys. How should one go about creating unique keys in webSQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [unique keyword](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm) and check for the [constraint error](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#dom-sqlexception-code-constraint) to verify.

```
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recs (id unique, fname, lname)'
```